# Do visual docking systems improve safety?

Tags: safety, airport, ground-operations, taxiing, airport-operations

Are there any studies that shows A-VDGS ([Advanced Visual Docking Guidance System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand_guidance_system#A-VDGS)) is improving the safety of aircraft movements on airports?

Comment: What is an A-VDGS?

Comment: @Terry Those are some kind of monitoring system helping to dock the aircraft to the passenger boarding bridges.